# How i can encrypt password send from html form to sh1 hash

Tags: php, html, encryption

I want to `encrypt` password send from an html form and then send it to `mysql`
Here's my code:

```
$password=<?php echo sha1($password); ?>
```

I get following error:

```
unexpected < error in ...... On line {line number}
```

How can I solve this or any other way to encrypt password send from form ?

Comment: use  `password_hash()`

Comment: and is `$password` php variable ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php  $password=sha1($password); ?>
```

try like this

Comment: SHA1 is not secure enough to store password.[See password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: I know it not but at this time I make lower security

Comment: Your idea vivek didn't solve My problem

Comment: whats the error it is showing? and can you provide full php code of your page?

Comment: its syntax error, whats problem ? in correcting it .. code you show isnt complete

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience,, I solved it successfully